# Error when trying to parse XML from SVN log command

Tags: php, svn, exec

I'm trying to build a simple drop down that will display the revisions of a specific file. From the option chosen, I use jQuery to fetch the current text contained in that revision and populate a textarea (using svn cat).

The header in my HTML file:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
```

My shell command:

```
svn log --xml "file:///C:/Documents and Settings/username_here/Desktop/svnrepo/Web/trunk/my_file.php"
```

XML parsing call:

```
$xmlData = simplexml_load_string(utf8_decode(trim(shell_exec($cmd))));
```

At this point, I get this error:

> Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate
>   encoding ! Bytes: 0xE9 0x20 0xE7 0x61

-I'm using the utf8_decode function to help display characters properly. For instance, "é" gets displayed as "Ã©"

-If I change the meta tag to utf-8, it displays properly. However, I need to have ISO-8859-1 per organizational set rules

-I'm calling my SVN repo using the file:/// protocol as a temporary measure for the moment

Funny enough, my jQuery call only necessitated a header call for it to display the characters properly (shell_exec(svn cat...)):

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1') ;
```

Comment: Why are you passing it through `utf8_decode`?  Remove that line.  As far as "to help display characters properly", you need to do that after the `simplexml_load_string` part, since the xml tag tells it to expect `utf8` characters...

Comment: You are correct. I removed it and applied it to my loop creating the drop down and it solved it. I seriously thought I had a tough one on my hands. Sigh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments, I removed the utf8_decode function when reading in the XML and applied it when displaying the text.

```
echo '<select id="selID">';
foreach ($xmlData->logentry as $entry){
 echo utf8_decode('<option value="'.$entry['revision'].'">rev '.$entry['revision'].' by '.$entry->author.' @ '.substr($entry->date,0,19).' '.$entry->msg.'</option>');
}
echo '</select><input type="button" id="svn_select" value="Load revision" />';
```

Works like a charm now.